# AppIntents issue when importing UIKit and using an Image for caseDisplayRepresentations of AppEnum

Tags: ios, swift, sirishortcuts, appintents

I’m creating a simple AppIntents Shortcut that requires UIKit to open a URL in my app. Though, once I add the `import UIKit` to my file, Xcode shows me the following warning at the `caseDisplayRepresentations`, because I use an image for the display repreentations. **Without importing UIKit (or without the image for the DisplayRepresentations) everything works fine!** Any ideas how to fix that?

> Expected a direct call to the `Image` initializer, got `Swift.Optional<AppIntents.DisplayRepresentation.Image>` instead

[image: Xcode Warning Screenshot]

#### The Code

```swift
import AppIntents
import UIKit

enum AppView: Int, AppEnum {
    case tab1
    case tab2
    
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation = TypeDisplayRepresentation(name: "View")
    
    static var caseDisplayRepresentations: [AppView : DisplayRepresentation] = [
        .tab1: DisplayRepresentation(title: "Tab 1",
                                     image: .init(systemName: "1.circle")),
        .tab2: DisplayRepresentation(title: "Tab 2",
                                     image: .init(systemName: "2.circle"))
    ]
}

// MARK: - Intent
struct OpenAppIntent: AppIntent {
    static let title: LocalizedStringResource = "Open App"
    static let description: IntentDescription = "Opens the app in the given view."
    
    // Launches app when action is triggered
    static let openAppWhenRun: Bool = true
    
    // App View Parameter
    @Parameter(title: "View",
               description: "The view inside the app.",
               default: .tab1,
               requestValueDialog: "Where would you like to navigate to?")
    var view: AppView
    
    // Shortcuts Action Text
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("Open \(\.$view)")
    }
    
    
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        if let url = URL(string: "myapp://\(view)") {
            await UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
        
        return .result()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I can see, when UIKit was imported, it changed the Image default initializer from returning Image to Optional<Image>.

Please focus on the Quick Help.
[image: Before]
[image: After]

You can solve this issue by force unwrapping the image (not recommended)

```
.init(systemName: "1.circle")!
```

or by helping Xcode specify your selected initializer.

```
.init(systemName: "1.circle", isTemplate: false)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that fast suggestion, that fixed it. Great idea to check the quick help.